# Problemas de proxy com OkHttp

Tags: java, proxy, okhttp

Eu estou usando a biblioteca [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) para fazer requisições da minha aplicação para a api do facebook, porém eu preciso trabalhar em uma rede com proxy, ao instanciar `OkHttpClient()` e chamar `OkHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()` eu recebo uma mensagem timeout porque o meu proxy para a requisição.

Após pesquisar um pouco eu encontrei a seguinte [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554380/okhttpclient-proxy-authentication-how-to):

```
int proxyPort = 8080;
String proxyHost = "proxyHost";
final String username = "username";
final String password = "password";

Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
  @Override public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
       String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
       return response.request().newBuilder()
           .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
           .build();
  }
};

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)))
    .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator)
    .build();
```

Isso funciona muito bem, porém eu não gostaria de deixar as informações do proxy no código ou na aplicação.

Existe alguma maneira de configurar o proxy como variavel de ambiente ou em algum arquivo externo onde o OkHttp conseguiria concluir as requisições?

Comment: [Isto](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) talvez lhe ajude.

Comment: [Isto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3457991/4319922) também.

Comment: Adotei a ideia de usar variáveis de ambiente mesmo, valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optei por usar a ideia das variáveis de ambiente conforme sugerido pelo StatelessDev